# after deleting compiz executable from bin directory , can't install it back?

Tags: software-installation, compiz, compiling

I have had a lot of issues with `compiz` , I have tried to remove it back , and after lots of trials I force removed it from bin dir

now I can't seem to be able to get it back ..

following installation guide from official site gives the following error 

`-- Could NOT find Lcov (missing:  LCOV_EXECUTABLE GENHTML_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find gcovr (missing:  GCOVR_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Checking for modules 'x11;xext;xdamage;xcomposite;xcursor;x11-xcb;xrandr;xinerama;xi;ice;sm;libxml-2.0;libxslt;glib-2.0;gio-2.0;glibmm-2.4;libstartup-notification-1.0 >= 0.7'
--   No package 'glibmm-2.4' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/CompizCommon.cmake:505 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:121 (compiz_pkg_check_modules)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/username/Desktop/compiz-0.9.13.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

#### edit

if you must know now I don't have a window manager .. windows dont move resize or scale .. they just stay still ..

Comment: Why are you trying to compile it, rather than installing the pre-built binary package from the repository?